# How to call custom Java method from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Please, what is the most convenient way how to call a Java method within Gradle build script? This method contain functionality I want to use during build; a piece of functionality too complex to be a in-script Groovy method but not enough to command full custom Gradle plugin.

My question is not about running a Java application from Gradle. That would involve forking JVM, and there is no simple way how to publish output back to Gradle and I need that output.

Initially I had my code in src/main/java but it has to be compiled early on to be callable from within Gradle build script.

Then I tried to move the build helper class to a submodule project, a one class submodule, hoping that the submodule would be builded before the main build script is called; in there I put:

```
 buildscript {
    dependencies {
       classpath 'this.project:build-helper:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
 }
```

But the `build-helper` subproject is clearly not build first, despite having in in `settings.gradle` as first and build fails as the dependency is not recognised. It seems buildscript is evaluated before submodules are built, before anything else. D'oh!

Answer (score 7):

There's two main use cases

**Source is in `src/main/java` in the current project** - Therefore the class does NOT exist when the buildscript classpath is defined

Options:

1. Use a [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task to run the class in another JVM
2. Construct a [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) from `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` and load / run the class via the classloader

eg:

```
task doStuff {
    doLast {
        URL[] urls = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files as URL[]
        def classloader = new URLClassLoader(urls, null)
        Class myClass = classloader.load("foo.bar.MyClass")
        def myInstance = myClass.newInstance()
        Method method = myClass.getMethod("doStuff")
        method.invoke(myInstance)
    }
}
```

**Source is in another project.** - Therefore the class will exist before the buildscript classpath is defined

In this case you can add the project to the buildscript classpath and invoke it

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath project(':other-project')
    }
}
task doStuff {
    doLast {
        def myClass = new MyClass()
        myClass.doStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the second advice but it didn't work for me, the project property wasn't allowed there and the helper project wasn't building. I have to use slightly outdated Gradle version 3.5 so perhaps that's why..

Comment: Ah, you are right... you could use a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) for this. See [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-monkey-patch/blob/master/spring-patch/build.gradle#L4) and [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-monkey-patch/blob/master/settings.gradle#L1)

Comment: Option one gives an error: cannot cast 'java.io.File' to 'java.net.URL'

Answer (score 4):

So the easiest way is to put my build helper Java source into `buildSrc` directory: `<project root dir>/buildSrc/src/main/java/foo/bar/Extractor.java` and that's it, you can call `new Extractor(..).extratMetadata(...)` directly from anywhere in Gradle build script, no need to import package, no need to use Java plugin, Gradle by default understands Maven like directory structure under buildScr.

Credits to: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/using-buildsrc-for-custom-logic-in-gradle-builds/

Answer (score 1):

To run your custom Java class from Gradle build script (without JVM fork) you can include it in the buildscript classpath and then import it explicitly. Example:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ownRepo = "${System.properties['user.home']}/.gradle/local"
    }
    // Repositories for the build script.
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url ownRepo
        }
    }
    // Dependencies for the build script.
    dependencies {
        classpath "org:mytool:1.0"
    }
}

import org.mytool.Checksums
task calculateChecksums() {
    doLast {
        new Checksums().calculate(myAppDir)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy

1. build your project files.
2. run this groovy file and call object method

```
        // This code is similar to lance-java's
        def files = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files
        // files[0] is C:\...\YourProject\build\classes\java\main
        def classLoader = new URLClassLoader((new URL[]{files[0].toURI().toURL()}))
        def myClass = Class.forName("aa.bb.c.MyClass", true, classLoader);
        def myInstance = myClass.newInstance()
        Method method = myClass.getMethod("sayHello")
        method.invoke(myInstance)
```

### Kotlin

1. build your project files.
2. run this groovy file and call class static method .

```
import java.net.URLClassLoader
...
task("helloworld") {
    doLast {
        val file: File = project.projectDir.toPath().resolve(tasks.jar.get().archiveFile.get().toString()).toFile()
        val classloader: ClassLoader = URLClassLoader(arrayOf(file.toURI().toURL()))
        Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass", true, classloader)
            .getMethod("sayHello").invoke(null)
    }
}
...
```